# Are points for an upvote 10 or 5?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

At times, an upvote gets me 10 reputation/point and other times 5. Enlighten me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get:

- **Five** points for an upvoted question
- **Ten** points for an upvoted answer

Since you've had both questions and answers upvoted, you've received points in both increments.

Answer (score 3):

There's a detailed post on MSO explaining all the different ways you can gain/lose reputation:

> [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)